# publish XML using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rss

I want to publish some data as XML from a SQL Server database using a WCF service to a location on our content delivery network. (www.somelocation-on-cdn/myxml.xml)

This data which is published as XML will have to be updated at an interval of time. I was thinking of writing a WCF service to return the data required, create a RSS reader to update / write the XML file to a location on the content delivery network.

Is this approach correct? Can I use WCF REST instead of WCF SOAP

As a further enhancement I want to be to use this WCF Service to make cross domain calls using JSONP from our website

Thanks

Comment: cross-domain?? Silverlight?? That's important - please add a "Silverlight" tag if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest path would be to use the [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) which is a layer on top of WCF REST services. It helps you by doing a lot of the mundane chores for you - you don't have to write quite as much code and deal with quite as many details.